# Angular 9 button click firing multiple times

Tags: javascript, angular

Html

```
<button (click)="myClickFunction($event)">
   Click Me
</button>
```

app.component.ts

```
myClickFunction(event) { 
      //just added console.log which will display the event details 
      console.log('inside myClickFunction');
   }
```

When I click on the button (named click me) multiple times, the console.log is printing multiple times. How to make it call only the first time irrespective of number of clicks?

I have tried event.preventdefault(), but getting following error:

```
Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you seeing multiple console.logs on one click? Is that what you meant? If not you can flag it with a counter maybe, I'll provide an answer

Comment: I am seeing multiple console.logs on multiple clicks. If we click one time, only one console log message.

Comment: Maybe specify that it is type="button" and not type="submit"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eko's Answer is correct but as you want the function to run only once it would be better to use Boolean instead.

```
private isClicked = false;

myClickFunction(event) { 
  if(this.isClicked){
    return;
  }
  this.isClicked = true;
  //just added console.log which will display the event details 
  console.log('inside myClickFunction');
}
```

Or you can disable the button in the function after click.

Comment: Clicking the button repeatedly multiple times, each time isClicked is coming false. Hence, multiple requests are served. not sure, why?

Comment: @Pearl Here I created something similar: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9eemua
It only works once. Can you show your code?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a counter to track the number of clicks and guard the click method with respect to that.

```js
private clickCounter = 0;

myClickFunction(event) { 
  if(this.clickCounter > 0){
    return;
  }
  this.clickCounter++;
  //just added console.log which will display the event details 
  console.log('inside myClickFunction');
}
```

Comment: Good answer but as he only wants to run it one time it's better to flag it with Boolean.